# Pure quantum phenomena from quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

Based on my background, I know quite lot of quantum phenomena that are mostly related to statistical physics and/or many-body quantum phenomena (superfluidity, superconductivity, some quantum effects in systems with disorder and quantum effects in transport phenomena, anomalous electron magnetic moment, Lamb shift, Casimir effect, etc). The key point is that all these effects are related to quantum field theory or can be treated in terms of QFT.

I would like to know something more about quantum effects that arise from simple quantum mechanics. To be honest, I remember only resonant tunneling and formation of Cooper pair (as I remember, it can be simply described as two particle problem). So, I have the following question:

**Can someone provide a book/reviews/references for pure quantum effects that can be treated in terms of simple quantum mechanics (without using of field theory concepts)? Especially, I am interested in phenomena that related to chemistry and/or biology (if exist).**

If my question is already having been asked, I would be grateful for links.

Comment: Would the energy levels in a hydrogen atom provide an example?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what this question is asking about - shouldn't every intro QM textbook contain such examples, like the double-slit or the Stern-Gerlach experiment?

Comment: @ACuriousMind the mentioned examples (hydrogen spectrum, Stern-Gerlach, double-slit) from my opinion are "quite trivial". Hydrogen atom levels are "simply" consequence of diff. eq. solution. The double-slit experiment is very "based". Stern-Gerlach is more interesting. Asking this question I mean more non-trivial effects. For instance, as I remember, Mössbauer effect can be considered in terms of QM and it is more interesting and non-trivial for me

Comment: I would like to close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this is quite what you have in mind but I recommend

> Raimond, Jean-Michel, and Serge Haroche. "Exploring the quantum." Oxford University Press (2006).

Nevermind that Haroche is a Nobel laureate (and Raimond is meritorious on his own) the book is subtitled *Atoms, Cavities and Photons* and focuses on these topics, especially modern developments, by which I mean mostly post Bell period.  It is at an intermediate to advanced level.  It does not focus on chemistry or biology.

Another good source is

> Budker D, Kimball D, Kimball DF, DeMille DP. “Atomic physics: an exploration through problems and solutions”. Oxford University Press, USA; 2004,

which explores various aspects of quantum mechanics applied to atoms as solved problems.  It is also not for the dilettantes, and the collection of problem is quite involved yet fascinating when it comes to understanding quantum phenomena in atoms and molecules under various conditions.

It doesn’t get more “quantum” than the above 2 if you want to stay out of QFT, but again, it is directed people with some experience with calculational quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thank you! I will check these books